# Oracle - select duplicate record having the most lower position in table

Tags: oracle11g, duplicates

I have table with the following structure:

```
Col1 | Col2
Qwe  | 99
Rty  | 67
Qwe  | 23
Uio  | 66
```

Table consists of duplicate records with the same `Col1` field. I need to extract records where `Col2` equals 23 and by that I mean the record that has the lowest position in the table. There can be more than 2 records with the same `Col1`. I can't query this by using a specific `Col1` value. Can it be done by using `rownum`? I can't check this, because I don't have access to a computer at the moment. Thanks in advance!

P.S. Typing from a phone...
P.S. Edits are very welcome...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the original table and I need to get 2nd, 5th, 6th and 7th because I need all non-duplicate records and one of each duplicates with the lowest position in table.

```
Col1 | Col2 | Col3
Qwe  | 99   | A
Rty  | 67   | B
Qwe  | 23   | A
Uio  | 66   | C
Uio  | 99   | C
Asd  | 11   | D
Qwe  | 45   | A
```

Solution was to create a temp table, that contains the actual rownum and max rownum for each record:

```
create table my_tab_temp as(
    select mt.*, 
           last_value(rownum) over (partition by mt.col3 order by mt.col3 desc) as max_rownum,   
           rownum "ROW_NUM"
    from my_tab mt
);
```

And the select the records that I need:

```
select * from my_tab_temp mtt
where mtt.max_rownum = mtt.row_num;
```

Result:

```
Col1 | Col2 | Col3
Qwe  | 45   | A
Rty  | 67   | B
Uio  | 99   | C
Asd  | 11   | D
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE Col2 = 23 GROUP BY Col1, Col2 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: Does "Select *" work if a "group by" is present. It does at least not work on DB2.

Comment: I can't query the table by using specific values, since query selects all records including duplicate row that has the lowest position

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM table t
WHERE t.id IN (
  SELECT MIN(t2.Id)
  FROM table t2
  WHERE t2.Col2 = 23
  GROUP BY t2.Col1
)
```

The query assumes that there is an`Id`-column that is primary key and uses it as row number. If there is no such column you will have to check if Oracle has a concept "row number".